# Spring Kafka manual acknowledge using AckMode.RECORD

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I am trying to use Kafka for the below use case that I have.

Our producer will produce messages to kafka topic. Our consumer is slow by nature because each message processing will vary depending on the content of the message. We are also batching the incoming messages based on some conditions and processing the list of batched messages in one go. We tried the below two approaches.

1. Multiple Partitions : With multiple partitions, we are able to batch and process the messages with the same consumer thread which is working fine, but when we have some smaller set of messages in the batch and our condition to process the batch is not met, we are waiting for new messages to come to process the existing messages which are already batched. We tried with time out but as the consumer thread wont execute until we get a message, we were never able to process the last chunk of messages.
2. One Partition - In memory queue : We tried with single partition which will write all the incoming messages to an in memory concurrent queue and we are spawning 5 threads(lets' say) using ExecutorService. All the threads were able to read unique messages from queue and process them. But the problem is with Acknowledgement. We are saving ack along with message in queue and trying to ack each message after processing. But what we observed is after partial processing from internal queue and if the consumer is restarted, I dont see other messages coming back to consumer. We are guessing this is because of the ack we are doing. Here the Ack mode id MANUAL/MANUAL_IMMEDIATE

Code below :

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "#{'${kafka-consumer.topics}'.split(',')}", groupId = "${kafka-consumer.groupId}", concurrency = "1")
public void consume(ConsumerRecord<String, String> record, Acknowledgment ack) throws InterruptedException {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(record.value());
        JSONArray request_data = jsonObject.getJSONArray("request");
        JSONObject data = request_data.getJSONObject(0);
        MessagePair messagePair = new MessagePair();
        messagePair.setMessage(data);
        messagePair.setAcknowledgment(ack);
        linkedQueue.add(messagePair);
        System.out.println("Queue size is : " + linkedQueue.size());

        if (executorService == null) {
            System.out.println("Starting executor service");
            executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                QueeuTask queeuTask = new QueeuTask(linkedQueue);
                System.out.println();
                executorService.execute(queeuTask);
            }
        }
}
```

The printList method below will be called by each executor thread after creating the batch based on custom conditions. Our actual processing will happen in the below method and after processing we are trying to acknowledge each message.

```
public void Printlist(ArrayList<MessagePair> lst, String threadName) throws InterruptedException {
        //Process the messages
        for(MessagePair pair : lst) {
            System.out.println("Sending acknowledgement for message : " + pair.getMessage());
            pair.getAcknowledgment().acknowledge();
        }
        lst.clear();
}
```

With the above implementation, we do see missing messages which are not processed in the local queue.

Can someone please help how can we achieve this acknowledgement to happen at each message. We have tried with AckMode.RECORD which says

**No Acknowledgment available as an argument, the listener container must have a MANUAL AckMode to populate the Acknowledgment**

Appreciate the help.

Comment: In other words, if I can control message offset commit in anyway such that I should be able to commit only messages that were processed. I understand this is beyond the kafka functionality, but wanted to know if someone had done any custom implementations to achieve the same.

Comment: The multi-partition approach is good, but you need to look into a higher `concurrency` option. Plus consider to use a batch mode for the listener container. There is no way to have a `RECORD` ack mode and expect an `Acknowledgment` in your code. It was never a good idea to shift the work from consumer thread into an executor: you just lose an order of offsets. The ack in Kafka is not per message, but per partition and if you commit let's say offset `10`, that means all the records with lower offset are committed as well. I always say that in perfect world we fully don't need to ack in Kafka.

Comment: Recent versions have a container property `asyncAcks` which allows out-of-order commits, by deferring the later commits, and pausing the consumer until all the gaps are filled. https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#ooo-commits However, if possible, it's much better to only process records serially.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. However, Even if I start processing serially, these records might finish in any order, in which case offset will go for a toss and if I do **asyncAcks** I will make the consumer wait until the gaps filled which will leave the consumer threads waiting and eventually add up to overall latency. Do you think of any other approach which I can use where I should do **asyncAck** and let consumer continue with other records

Comment: Also will you recommend to use Kafka when the consumer is slow and messages can be finished in any order irrespective of the order they came in, with the POC I tried, if the offset of a later messages is committed, we are missing earlier messages when consumer goes down as kafka consider all the messages under the offset as committed

Comment: Can you suggest how you handled dropping of messages when the offset of a later messages is committed, we are also missing earlier messages when consumer goes down as kafka consider all the messages under the offset as committed; What is the solution to this and best way to implement the consumer so that this problem is not faced?

Comment: Hello, we have changed our design to make the incoming messages more light weight in terms of processing and also then sending a list of these light weight messages as a single message to our consumer. This way we are able to speed up the process and retry and ack/nack will also be limited to a small chunk. With slow consumer and asynchronous acks, it would be difficult to control the drop of messages. One way that I see is to handle acks manually by checking the completion status of all older messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After analyzing the use case, we have changed the design to make sure kafka consumers will not be slow. We are also handling offset commits to make sure processing is finished. With the new use case, we are using Kafka batch listener to read a fixed messages in one poll and create equal loads to the actual process and kafka listener to process these loads which is not very processing intensive. Thanks for all the suggestions.